# DefaultHttpContent instead of HttpResponse in netty 4.0.23

Tags: netty

I have the following pipeline configuration for a Http Client  -

```
pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler());      
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpResponseDecoder());     
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpRequestEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("handler", new MySimpleChannelInboundHandler());
```

In `MySimpleChannelInboundHandler`'s `channelRead0()` method, I get an instance of `DefaultHttpContent` instead of `HttpResponse`. When I log the `DefaultHttpContent`'s content using -

```
DefaultHttpContent content = (DefaultHttpContent) msg;          
LOG.debug(content.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

I can see the actual HTTP response being logged.

Why is this HTTP response not being decoded into a `HttpResponse` object even though I have a HTTP decoder in the pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpObjectAggregator` before the enc/decoders in order to aggregate httpResponse and all the following HttpContents. After adding the `HttpObjectAggregator` in the pipeline you'll get a `FullHttpResponse` object in your handler.

eg : `p.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));`

one more thing, if you not implementing your own enc/decoders for client, you can you netty's provided `HttpClientCodec`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that using an `HttpObjectAggregator` in my pipeline after the `HttpDecoder` will result in a `FullHttpResponse`. But my problem is - without the `HttpObjectAggregator`, I should be getting one `HttpResponse`, 0 to n `HttpContent` and one `LastHttpContent`. But I only get one `DefaultHttpContent` (which has the correct response). I tried adding an `HttpObjectAggregator` after the decoder and I got a `NullPointerException` at the aggregator's `channelRead0()`. Also, I cannot use `HttpClientCodec` as I am modifying an existing library that uses the enc/dec.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. The `HttpResponseDecoder` had earlier decoded a response to an HTTP CONNECT request. I did not override the `isContentAlwaysEmpty(HttpMessage httpMessage)` method to return false for the CONNECT request. This had left the `HttpResponseDecoder` in a bad state. It was expecting the content in the response, but the response to HTTP CONNECT did not have one. When the response to the next request arrived, it was taken as the content and not decoded into a `HttpResponse`.

I extended `HttpResponseDecoder` and overrode (overrided?) `isContentAlwaysEmpty(HttpMessage httpMessage)` to return false for the CONNECT request and it worked. This is documented in the `HttpResponseDecoder`'s [class level documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpResponseDecoder.html) under "Decoding a response for a CONNECT request".